# Taking control a command for men and it's meaning

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grammar-dikduk, commentaries, parashat-bereishit

With so many words which describe ruling, submission, dominion, leading, controling, reagning etc.

I wondered why the word mashal was chosen in Bereshit 3:16 and rarah and kabash in Bereshit 1:26-28, what do these words add to the meaning of the context? In what way should a men rule a wife's desire? And in what way should men subdue the earth and control the animals?

Answer (score 1):

Wife's desire and he will rule over her
The desire: She wants to have relations
He rules: she can not demand them (verbally)  he is the only one ruling and active in starting the relations
Rashi on the posuk ([sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.3.16.4), [Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/8167#showrashi=true&v=16))

Wife's desire is that she wants relations, when her husband goes away.
Talmud [Yevamot 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.17)

Control the animals, is Regarding using them for labor
Talmud [Sanhedrin 59b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.59b.16)